# Остановить программу на Си

Tags: c

Вот такой вот код.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
     float x,y;
     scanf ("%f",&x);
     if (x == 0){
        printf("No result");
     }else{
           y=sin(x)/x;
           printf("y= %f",y);
     }
return 0;
}
```

Как тормознуть выполнение на выводе?
пробовал getchar() но что то никак

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить `getch`? Попробуйте:

```
printf("y= %f",y);
getch();
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще раз

```
scanf ("%f",&x);
```

вызовите в конце и все.

**P.S.** Все-таки "вызовите" с маленькой буквы, ибо предложение в моей голове звучало как "Еще раз сканф вызовите в конце и все.". Если это грамматически неверно, то поправьте еще раз.

Comment: Или `getch();`, или `while(!kbhit());`....

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что при нажатии [Enter] в поток стандартного ввода кроме набранных Вами символов числа заносится символ перевода строки ('\n'). getchar() считывает его и программа не дожидается следующего [Enter], чего Вы видимо хотите.

Реально,  в Вашем случае (*я думаю это консоль в Виндоус*), вызовите (как уже отвечено [@Tim](/users/3288/tim) и [@gecube](/users/907/gecube)) **getch()**. Эта функция ожидает нажатия символа на клавиатуре и возвращает его код. Данный символ не заносится (!) в поток стандартного ввода и более того, даже в случае если это ^Z не закрывает поток (EOF в таком случае Вы не получите).

**kbhit()** опрашивает клавиатуру без ожидания ("жрет процессор") и возвращает 0, если никакая клавиша не нажата и 1 (не код введенного символа!) если что-нибудь нажали. Код нажатой клавиши помещается в конец потока стандартного ввода.

Надеюсь эта информация окажется Вам полезной при программировании ввода с консоли.